# Java: Calling function in "this" class rather than a subclass (analog to "super")

Tags: java, inheritance

Is it possible in Java to invoke an overridable method in such a way that it always executes the "locally defined" version rather than an overridden version from a subclass? I.e. is there an analog to `super` that refers to this class, rather than the super class?

Let me give a code example to hopefully make it clear what I'm trying to do:

```
class A {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo from A");
    }

    void bar() {
        foo();  // <-- This is the important line!
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo from B");
    }
}
```

If I do `new B().bar()`, it will call the `bar()` method defined in `A`, which calls `foo()` as overridden in `B` to print "Foo from B".

Is there a way that I can force the `bar()` method to call the `foo()` method as defined in `A` rather than `B`? Just like I can use `super.foo()` in `B` to call the `foo()` method as defined in `A`? Unfortunately using `this.foo()` still calls the version of the subclass. Even something like `((A) this).foo()` or `A.this.foo()` doesn't work.

Clearly, I could simply define a private or final version of `foo()` in `A` and call that instead. But I am hoping for a solution, where all I do is change the "important line" in the code sample above to a  different way of invoking foo() to have it print "Foo from A", preferably without some trick like reflection.

Comment: Which `foo()` is called is determined by the type of the **value** (the instance), not by the type of the **variable**, i. e. `A a = new B(); a.foo();` calls `B.foo()`.

Comment: It looks like you found one of the (many) problems of inheritance. You would do well to use composition instead of inheritance, this will produce a code that's a lot easier to read, understand and figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @Guillaume I'm surprised this doesn't come up often enough to have been solved. I'm thinking for example of all the base-type classes like OutputStream that provide fallback method implementations like write(byte[] b) by forwarding them to write(int b). If you overwrite both, you can't use super any more to make use of the fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make your methods static (baadddddd), either change your design.

Indeed, it makes no sense to provide the default behavior for a subclass that it is defined to adapt itself to the concerned method.

As your `foo()` method seems to vary, you may implement a Strategy Pattern like this:

```
interface BarProcess{
    void foo();
}

public class DefaultBarProcess implements BarProcess{
    void foo() {
       System.out.println("Foo from A");
    }
}

public class AnotherBarProcess implements BarProcess{
    void foo() {
       System.out.println("Foo from B");
    }
}

class A {

    private BarProcess barProcess;

    public A(Bar barProcess){
      this.barProcess = barProcess;
    }

    void bar() {
        barProcess.foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {  //deprecated! No need to exist

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object **is** a `B`. It **isn't** an `A`! Here's an example:

```
public class Apple {
    public void printColor() {
        System.out.println("I am red");
    }

    public void bar() {
       printColor();
    }
}
```

Then the subclass:

```
public class GrannySmithApple extends Apple {
    public void printColor() {
        System.out.println("I am green");
    }
}
```

`GrannySmithApple`s **are green**, always (unless they are rotten, but that's a whole other can of bananas)! Once you have a `GrannySmithApple`, it's **not** an `Apple` anymore, except in the sense that you can do all the same things with it that you could a regular `Apple` (`printColor`, `eat`, etc.) Make sense? And anything that hasn't changed between the conversion from regular `Apple` to `GrannySmithApple` is obviously still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an "internal" `foo()` in A that is called.

```
class A {
    private void fooInternal() {
        System.out.println("Foo from A");
    }

    void foo() {
        fooInternal();
    }

    void bar() {
        fooInternal();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo from B");
    }
}
```

`new B().bar()` will now print "Foo from A" while `new B().foo()` will print "Foo from B".

Comment: @Mik378 Can you explain how the overridden method would be called if calling `new B().bar()`.

Comment: That'll work. That's what I meant in the beginning of the last paragraph of my question as a possible, but not so elegant solution.

Comment: What do you think will work here? The method that **IS** overridden in subclass will still be called if you invoke it from subclass object. You **don't achieve anything** with this construct

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` always invokes instance method of the class used in `new ...` statement.

In short I think that the answer to your question is **NO**, it can't be done. It would prevent you from overriding parts of behaviour completely.

```
class A {

method1() {
...
method2();
...
}

class B extends A {

// You can override method2 here to change the behaviour of method1 
// because it will call **your** version of method2
// You **don't** have to override method1 to achieve that

method2() {
...
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a `B` object will always call its own `foo()` method. With that said, `B.foo()` can be defined to call the superclass' `foo()` method. For example, you could define `B` as follows:

```
class B extends A {
    @Override public void foo() {
        super.foo();
    }
}
```

And doing so will have `B` call `foo` from `A`. But doing so will have it always do so.

Comment: It's strange to me that Java offers 'super' but no analog for 'me' or 'here' or 'local' or 'this' or something the like...

Comment: Yes but "this" means this object, not this class... So if the object is a B, this will actually call a method on B (even though it's called from A)

Comment: @Markus It's best to imagine inheritance as `B` literally copying all the methods from `A`. That way, when `bar()` calls `foo()` it's going to refer to its own `foo()` unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

**There is this Rule of Thumb:**

```
In Inheritance the most specific version of the method for that class is called.
```

**-** So it will be always the `foo()` method of `Class B` that will be called, if its called on an **instance of B**.

**-** Still if you want the `foo()` method of `Class A` to be called using your above mentioned code then you will need the `super` keyword.

**Eg:**

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    void foo() {

       super.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` references "this object", not "this class".

That means if you have an object `B` that extends `A`, when it executes a method in the superclass `A` that mentions `this`, it will actually point to the instance of `B`, so will execute the method on `B`.

You can think of the method in `A` as a **default method**. If the method is overridden in your actual object `B`, then it will **always** be called instead.

I suggest you **change your design** and use **composition instead of inheritance**: that would ensure a clear separation of concern, and make your code a lot easier to understand and test.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated there is no direct way to do it but you might consider a variant of this construct:

```
  void bar() {
    ClassA self = new ClassA();
    self.foo();  // <-- This is the important line!
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that way foo() would loose access to all local variables. But "self" would be a great keyword to use for this scenario! :)