# How to force call superclass implementation Object.toString() rather than subclass overriding implementation on an object in Java

Tags: java, overriding, superclass, subclassing

> **Please note:** I am not asking how to force all classes to override `toString()` in their source code. Please read the question carefully.

All classes in java extend the `Object` class. If any class has a `toString()` override, a call to `Object.toString()` will actually execute the overriding method.

For example:

```
String test = "StackOverflow";
Object testobj1 = (Object) test;
System.out.println(testobj1.toString()); // prints "StackOverflow"
Object testobj2 = new Object();
System.out.println(testobj2.toString()); // prints "java.lang.Object@<Object.hashcode() in hex>"
```

What I need is for a call to `testobj1`'s `toString()` to actually execute the `Object` class's `toString()` method. Something like:

```
System.out.println( [[testobj1 as Object]] .toString()); // prints "java.lang.String@<Object.hashcode() in hex>"
```

I tried using:

```
System.out.println(testobj1.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(testobj1.hashCode()));
```

But this also has the same problem as above. The `hashCode()` method is also overriden by `String` class, so it is executing `String`'s `hashCode()`, not `Object`'s `hashCode()`.

**Is it possible to call the overridden method, rather than the overriding method?**

> **Please note:** The use of `String` class is merely an example. Do not base your answer on the assumption that the object is always a `String` object.
>
> **Also assume:** I have no access to the source code of classes, so I can't just remove `toString()` implementation from them or do things like creating an abstract class. This has to work for **any** object (including that of Java's own classes or any API like `String`, `HashMap`, `HttpServlet`, etc). This also means that I'm **not** looking for answers [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13403017/1134080).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `System.identityHashCode()` to get the actual (original) hash code.

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "StackOverflow";
    Object testobj1 = (Object) test;
    System.out.println(testobj1.toString()); // prints "StackOverflow"
    System.out.println(testobj1.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(testobj1)));
    System.out.println(test.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(test)));
    Object testobj2 = new Object();
    System.out.println(testobj2.toString()); 
    System.out.println(testobj2.getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(testobj2)));
}
```

Output:

```
StackOverflow
java.lang.String@5d888759
java.lang.String@5d888759
java.lang.Object@2e6e1408
java.lang.Object@2e6e1408
```

Comment: Close enough! Totally forgot about that method. It's not a generic solution, but it works for getting back the original functionality of `Object.toString()`!

Comment: @ADTC - Yes, it does.. overridden methods are dynamically dispatched so I don't see any other way here.

Comment: Yeah but this will work for me as I'm only looking to replicate `toString()`. But I wonder if a generic solution is possible using **reflection**? *Probably an overkill, but is it possible?*

Comment: @ADTC - I don't think so.. Irrespective of how ypu encapsulate it, *internally*, the object is still a `String`. So, `hashCode()` of String is called *always*. BTW you are already using reflection here..`getClass().getName()` :P

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do like this.

Because java always use overriding method.

Its not call overridden method. That doesn't make sense .you are overriding a method because you are no need to use parent method.

Comment: Although your edited answer directly answers my question, TheLostMind's answer solves my actual problem. I will be inclined to accept that instead. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I've actually stopped asking people *why are you trying to do this?*.. :P

Comment: what you have stopped to ask this