# Java: make a function not virtual - call parent method on parent reference

Tags: java, polymorphism

I would think this question has been asked before, but was not immediately able to find an answer.

Say, somehow, a `Pet` reference is assigned a `Dog` object:

```
Pet pet = new Dog();
```

If I write

```
pet.attackInvader();
```

The child class (`Dog`)'s method is called by virtue that all functions in Java are virtual.

Is it possible to invoke `Pet`'s `attackInvader()` instead?

(I know I can edit `Dog`'s method to call `super`, but, in this case, assume I cannot change `Dog`'s implementation.)

Comment: I know it's been asked before, I'll search for it...

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible (without gross reflection).

Comment: You can't because the designs of java prevent you from doing that. It's a safety/security feature. The only way is if you are able to modify `Dog`'s method to call `super()`

Comment: Closest I could find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403017/java-calling-function-in-this-class-rather-than-a-subclass-analog-to-super?rq=1

Comment: @AndyTurner I disagree that it's a duplicate of that particular question, even if it's almost certainly a duplicate.  `super()` doesn't help if you can't modify `Dog`.

Comment: @O.KOO Thanks for confirming this is not possible. But could you elaborate on why it would be a safety/security concern?

Comment: D M, thanks for the link - that question is indeed similar. But I suppose in my case, if one really wants to make sure the base class's method is called, one can use `final` to make sure `Pet` is not inherited...

Comment: `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` provides a fragile workaround. You basically reflectively invoke the private `MethodHandles.Lookup(Class<?>, int)` constructor with { `Pet.class`, `Lookup.PRIVATE` }, then call `findSpecial` on the lookup object to get a `MethodHandle` describing the non-overridden method, and finally invoke it via the handle, on your `pet` (`Dog`) instance. I believe to have come across at least one answer demonstrating this approach, but am unable to find it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without overriding the method in `Dog` and without changing the instantiated object from `Dog` to `Pet`, it is not possible as the polymorphism works in this way : 
the method invoked at runtime is always the method of the runtime object.

Now as alternative, you could provide a method in `Dog` that convert it into a `Pet` instance :

```
  public Pet toPet(){
      return new Pet(...);
 }
```

and then invoke `attackInvader()` :

```
myDog.toPet().attackInvader();
```

Or by creating a new method in `Dog` that offers this specific behavior :

```
  public void attackInvaderPet(){
      super.attackInvader();
  }
```